# Is it posssible to edit display settings for CLI/in Code for Windows 11?

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors

I want to be able to have presets for display/audio settings.
For example

Gaming-TV: Go show only the TV as primary and send the audio too.
Normal-PC: Show 1 monitor primary, other as secondary, also secondary is vertical, disable TV.
etc...

I did not find any settings file or API for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Windows 11 does not support this on its own.

But you can use free (gratis) third-party tools from [Nir Sofer](https://www.nirsoft.net) to accomplish these goals.

You can create Windows shortcuts to Nir's [MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) to switch screens.  You can then assign keyboard shortcuts to those shortcuts.

For audio, you can do the same using Nir's [SoundVolumeView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html), or the command-line (CLI) equivalent, [SoundVolumeCommandLine](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_command_line.html).

You can write simple batch files that handle both the screen and audio together.  You can then create Windows shortcuts to those batch files.  Finally, you can assign keyboard shortcuts to those Windows shortcuts.